# jmeter proxy: how to unzip traffic during / before recording

Tags: proxy, jmeter, compression

The http traffic I'm interested in recording is gzipped (the client sends zipped data to the server). The result is recorded binary traffic which cannot be easily modified. It's very difficult to modify the client in order to suppress compression. So my question: Is there an option or extension for the proxy to uncompress the client traffic during recording?

Comment: Did you find a workable solution?

Answer (score 0):

My environment:
The client sends compressed requests.
The server sends compressed responses.

My requirements:
I have to modify the requests.
I have to check assertions in the responses.

Your advice:
JMeter can not handle the compressed  traffic in the required way.
Disable compression on both sides.

Right?

Comment: I personally haven't worked in such an environment, the link below seemed like a good solution - cheers.